# Conditional Expectation of solution to SDE

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $g \in C^{1,2,2}$ and $X_t$ and $Y_t$ solve some SDEs
$$
dY_t = a(t,X_t,Y_t)dt +b(t,X_t,Y_t)dW_t
$$
and 
$$
dX_t = c(t,X_t)dt + d(t,X_t)d\tilde{W}_t
$$, then Iio's lemma implies 
$$
g(t,X_t,Y_t)
$$
also solves a certain SDE.

My question is, if $\mathfrak{F}_t$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tilde{W}_t$, then does
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(t,X_t,Y_t)|\mathfrak{F}_t],
$$
also satisfy an SDE?  If so what?

Comment: Very closely related is taking conditional expectation given the history $\mathcal{G}_t$ of $X_t$ instead of $\tilde W_t$. In that case you have an S\emph{P}DE for the (unnormalized) conditional density of $Y_t$, from which $\mathbb{E}[g(t,X_t,Y_t)|\mathcal{G}_t]$ can be calculated.

Comment: This sounds interesting, could you post a link to some material on this?

Comment: Many books on SPDEs will have at least a brief introduction to this, Rozovskii's "Stochastic evolution systems" even has this in the subtitle. There is also a short but rigorous (and perhaps very dense) section about this in Krylov's "An analyic approach to SPDEs".

Comment: I do have one question though, if $X_t$ and $Y_t$ take values in a Hilbert space, is there any literature on that, version of the problem?